# Extending maples latex function to support siunitx

Tags: siunitx, conversion, units

In maple there is a function called `latex` which can convert a maple expression to an equivalent latex expression.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to properly use units with the conversion function:

```
> with(Units[Standard]):
> latex(Unit('m'))
{\it Unit} \left( m \right)
```

According to the documentation for `latex` I need to implement a function called `latex/Unit`, however:

```
> `latex/Unit` := proc (v) "test" end proc:
> latex(Unit('m'));
{\it Unit} \left( m \right)
```

How can I create a function which would properly convert expressions to latex using siunitx?

While `\SI{5.523}{m}` would be preferred over `5.523\si{m}`, the second format is also ok.

If possible I would also like numbers to be changed to output as `\num{5.5}` instead of just `5.5`, but I'm much more concerned about units. Of course using `\meter` instead of `m` in the unit is also preferrable, but not as important.

Comment: I guess you already know [How latex Formats Functions](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=latex/functions), but it might be insightful to people wanting to provide help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Maple problem rather than a LaTeX problem.

Still, the basic issue is that `Unit( 'm' )` gets evaluated before being passed to `latex`. Look at the effect of the uneval quotes in the following:

```
> latex( int( 1 / x , x ) ) ;
\ln  \left( x \right) 
> latex( 'int'(1 / x , x ) ) ;
\int \!{x}^{-1}\,{\rm d}x
```

So, in your case, the `latex/Unit` function is never called at all. You could use

```
> latex('Unit'('m'));
```

after which you still have some work to do in order to produce the results you want, but at least the function is executed. I'll try to think up a way to implement a less cumbersome syntax tomorrow.

Comment: If I convert from one unit to another, I get evaluated units, so I can't really do this on values I get from computations. If you could find the function that *is* called, it would be great. Alternatively if you know how to separate the unit from the rest of the value, I can use that to write a wrapper.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't seem to work with `Unit` anyway. Perhaps the problem is caused by the fact that `Unit` is a module, not a procedure. In any case, I think this is one to take up with Maplesoft Technical Support. I'd be interested to see their response; my email address can be obtained from my profile page.